# Multiple choice question trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = cos(|π −x|)+(x−π)sin|x|$ and $g(x) = x^2$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If $h(x) = f(g(x))$, then

(1) $h$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$

(2) $h(\sqrt{\pi}) = 0$

(3) $h(x) = 0$ has a solution in $(−\pi , \pi)$

(4) there exists $x_0 \in (−\pi, \pi)$ such that $h(x_0) = x_0.$

We can conclude 1 and 2 directly, $h$ is differentiable as both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable.  How about $3$ and $4$?

Comment: Why do you post problems $1$ and $2$ if you know their answer?  Why waste our time dealing with those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying you think $h(\sqrt{\pi}) = 0$?

Hint for others:

[image]

Comment: Without using graphing toola, can we conclude 2,3

Comment: $h(\sqrt{\pi}}=1$

Comment: Yes, of course.  We know that $h(x)$ is continuous and above $x$ at $-\pi$ and above $x$ at $\pi$.  QED.  And yes, $h(\sqrt{\pi}) = 1$, from direct substitution or reading from the graph.

Comment: All you need to know is that $\displaystyle h( x)$ is continuous and  $\displaystyle h\left( \ -\sqrt{\pi } \ \right) =1$ and $\displaystyle h( 0) =-1$ to see that both (3) and (4) are true.